# Spacing from outer space

Tags: html, css

I just wonder where is this space between the end of the image and the end of the li's are coming from:

http://bluesys.ch/lussy/

its just  a simple UL > li > img

[spacing from hell http://bluesys.ch/lussy/spacingfromhell.jpg](http://bluesys.ch/lussy/spacingfromhell.jpg)

code:

```
div#slider {
    border: 5px solid #fff;
}

div#slider ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid pink;
}

div#slider ul li img {
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
    margin: 0;
}
```

note that all margins and paddings are set to 0 by my reset.css

can someone help me out? I colored the borders that you can see the spacing i speak of. I use firefox.

Comment: Perhaps a screen capture would help, I am not seeing any space that appears unwanted.

Comment: @jye: After each image there is a small (4 or 5 px) gap to the next picture (at least in IE8). I believe that's what the OP is referring to.

Comment: added a screenshot for you. <3

Comment: I see what you are referring to now - not sure as yet why it is rendering that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the line-height to 0 for those images and/or LI elements. Currently you have that set to 1.4 in the body, and the img will inherit that. A brief test of setting `line-height: 0` in Firebug made the images stack flush.

Comment: it worked! i love you! since when lineheight applies on IMG or LI's tags withount any text in it??

Comment: The line-height is applicable to <li>

Comment: why does lineheight apply on a block type object?

Comment: @meo: Images are actually inline objects (sometimes inline-block). The point is, they are subject to line-height styling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the gaps, you could try:

```
li  {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

You may want a special class for those `li` elements tho, so that the CSS that gets applied doesn't do it to ALL your `li` elements on the site.

But, what's wrong w/ the gap? I kind of like it. Helps frame each image...

Comment: i gonna do an image slider with it :P the images are gonna overlap, but i have to get rid of this spaceing befor :( i already set all margins ad paddings to 0m in reset.css

Answer (score 0):

Images are inline elements just like text and by default they are positioned on the font base line leaving space for the ascender. There are different ways to stop that:

- `line-height: 0` (as suggested by Robusto)
- `display: block`
- `vertical-align: bottom`

Comment: I meant to say to apply it to the image, not the `li`